# Can I sign into Facebook

Tags: help

I am new here. My question pertains to signing into Facebook off of Tor. If I use the Tor Browser to sign into Facebook and I have a stalker of some sort monitoring my phone not the actual facebook account, will it show my personal information to him. Ex.(he is a stalker) Will he get my new password that I used, be able to tell what I posted or get any of my messages? And If not, is there any particular safe browser that I could use? I know that if i post something everyone will know who i am. i just want to be clear. I am referring to someone that is monitoring the actual phone itself.

Comment: what are they actually doing? how much do they already know?

Comment: if they are just monitoring the phone, why can't you just sign in on a normal web browser?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook can technically be used with the Tor Browser. This is how many people access Facebook despite filters or other restrictions on their network.

Tor will prevent Facebook from knowing the Internet connection used to access it.
But sharing data on Facebook is *sharing data*. It means that it will be be stored on Facebook servers and accessible by other Facebook users depending on “privacy settings”.

If you suspect your computer to be compromised with spying software, using the [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) live system will prevent them to work (unless they are working at a very low-level).

Comment: Tails has not been adapted to a mobile devices. She is talking about a phone.

Answer (score 1):

If your device is comprimised, the hacker can see what you do before you send it over the Tor network. Tor will protect against an attacker monitoring your connection, not your device. Also, Facebook may treat Tor as an unrecognized device and make fill out a ridculous test to log on.

As the other answer mentioned, be sure your account is secure. You should probably look into anti-spyware software (anti-virus and anti-malware as well). Perhaps get your device professionally examined. There are specially secured operating systems that can be loaded onto some phones: Cyanogen Mod or Replicant for Android devices.

Finally, it would seem that the digital component of your problem is not the most significant component of it. It may be more beneficial to direct your efforts there.